# Setting the time in unix with python from server

Tags: python, linux, date, unix, time

I'm trying to set the time in linux with python. I got the date and time , what i need to do the set the time that i got in my system?

```
import os
import ntplib
from datetime import datetime,timezone
c = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = c.request('ch.pool.ntp.org',version = 3)
response.offset
data = datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, timezone.utc)
time = data.time()
date = data.date()
time1 =time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
os.system('date --set %s' % date)
```

This is the code i wrote to get the time from a server .
in bold it's what i tried and it not working.

Comment: Why not using NTP directly from the linux box? See https://www.dyclassroom.com/reference-server/how-to-sync-linux-server-time-with-ntp-network-time-protocol-server

Comment: Anyway the commands you should call are: `date -s "2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"` OR `date --set="2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"`

Comment: Do you want to set a timezone or a custom date? Which linux are you using?

Comment: @balderman awesome. your way is much better. Do you know away to do that in windows powerShell?

Comment: @adirb Please explain what are you looking for. Do you still want to go with the python script or configure the linux box to use NTP directly?

Comment: @balderman I think the direct way is much better for what i need if i can schedule it for running once a day. can i do that?

Comment: @adirb You dont have to.. ('running once a day..'). The ntpd will take care of it.

Comment: @balderman Yes i know , but i need it to do it for different countries. let's say i need in 9am to get U.S time and in 16pm China time. can i do that with cron?

Comment: @adirb Let me see if I understand. During  24 hours you want the date of the machine to point to U.S date and after few hours you want to point to China date?

Comment: @balderman Yes. i need the option to schedule it

Comment: In this case you can just use `timedatectl` via cron. But since you play with the computer date you have to be careful with the cron scheduling. See https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/configuring-date-and-timezone.html

Comment: @balderman Thank you! do you know a way for doing the same in windows powerShell?

Comment: @adirb I am glad to help. You can vote up if my answer brings value to you. I think that windows powershell deserve a different question.

Comment: Ummm ... why not set the machine to UTC and never worry about any of this ever again? If you change the TZ several times a day you won't be getting very meaningful logs ...

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
import os
# TOOD use real date
rv = os.system('date -s "2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"')
if rv == 0:
   print('date was set')
else:
   print('date was not set')
```

Or you can configure your linux to use [NTP server](https://www.dyclassroom.com/reference-server/how-to-sync-linux-server-time-with-ntp-network-time-protocol-server).